# matching columns from different file & aggregating the values from particular coulmns using shell script

Tags: file, shell, unix, awk, sed

Hi I have multiple files having same rows but different data. I want to match data according to date & time in all the files and have output as aggregate of some specific rows.

FILE 1

```
DATE     TIME        A     B    C   D         
20140402 00:15:26   21    50   30  60        
20140402 00:20:04   23    54   40  70        
20140402 00:25:04   25    52   50  80
```

FILE 2

```
DATE     TIME        A     B    C   D        
20140402 00:15:21   40    60   60  70       
20140402 00:20:29   50    61   70  80       
20140402 00:25:22   60    63   80  90       
20140402 00:30:26   70    70   90  40       
20140402 00:35:23   80    80   65  50       
20140402 00:40:27   50    65   76  60
```

FILE 3

```
DATE     TIME         A     B   C    D       
20140402 00:15:24     10    50  10   50      
20140402 00:20:03     20    60  40   60      
20140402 00:25:03     30    70  50   70      
20140402 00:30:24     10    80  70   80      
20140402 00:35:03     50    90  80   10
```

OUTPUT :

```
DATE     TIME         B         D            
20140402 00:15        160       180          
20140402 00:20        175       210          
20140402 00:25        185       240          
20140402 00:30        150       120          
20140402 00:35        170       130          
20140402 00:40         65        60
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
awk 'FNR!=1 {split($2,a,":");arr_b[$1 FS a[1]":"a[2]]+=$4;arr_d[$1 FS a[1]":"a[2]]+=$6} END {for (i in arr_b) print i,arr_b[i],arr_d[i]}' OFS="\t" file?
20140402 00:25  185     240
20140402 00:35  170     60
20140402 00:20  175     210
20140402 00:30  150     120
20140402 00:40  65      60
20140402 00:15  160     180
```

To get it sorted:

```
awk 'FNR!=1 {split($2,a,":");arr_b[$1 FS a[1]":"a[2]]+=$4;arr_d[$1 FS a[1]":"a[2]]+=$6} END {for (i in arr_b) print i,arr_b[i],arr_d[i]}' OFS="\t" file? | sort -k1 -k2
20140402 00:15  160     180
20140402 00:20  175     210
20140402 00:25  185     240
20140402 00:30  150     120
20140402 00:35  170     60
20140402 00:40  65      60
```

`file?` can be replaced by `file1 file2 file3`

---

How does it work:

```
awk '
FNR!=1 {                            # Do this for all line except header
    split($2,a,":")                 # Split the time field into array "a"
    arr_b[$1 FS a[1]":"a[2]]+=$4    # Sum value of "B" column into array "arr_b"
    arr_d[$1 FS a[1]":"a[2]]+=$6    # Sum value of "D" column into array "arr_d"
    }
END {
    for (i in arr_b)                # Loop trough all element in array "arr_b"
        print i,arr_b[i],arr_d[i]   # Print the value of index, "arr_b" and "arr_d"
    }
    ' OFS="\t" file?                # Set output field separator to tab and read the files
```

Comment: Hi Jotne, I could not find Where the coding is matching for time stamps in different files. My requirement is that, 1st the time should be matched & then the aggregation shoul take place

Comment: Its done by store it into `arrays` using time as an ID. So if time is the same, add up data. Same approach as @Tichodroma muraria has used too. Result is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ gawk '/2014/ { print $1, substr($2, 0, 5), $4, $6 }' < ?.txt |\
sort |\
gawk '{ B[$1 " "  $2] += $3; D[$1 " " $2] += $4 } END {for (k in B) {print k, B[k], D[k]}}' |\
sort
20140402 00:15 160 180
20140402 00:20 175 210
20140402 00:25 185 240
20140402 00:30 150 120
20140402 00:35 170 60
20140402 00:40 65 60
```